# Webpage in Google Chrome: body background-color transparent?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, fullscreen, transparent

is there a chance to get a transparent webpage in google chrome? So that I can use

```
<body style="background-color: transparent">
```

on a webpage and the webpage shows me - for example - my desktop-wallpaper and all other icons on my desktop?

History: I want to show videos in the vlc-player in fullscreen-mode and display a ticker, written in jquery, above the video. Or is there a better way to do this?

greetings, Franky

Comment: I'm fairly sure that is not possible.

Comment: Hm.. Maybe there is a "switch" to turn on a "transparent mode" in chrome (or ff, ie..)? its just only for me! it must not be a only - internet-solution.. i have access to the whole system ;)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've got a solution for my problem. I will use awesomium ([awesomium.com](http://labs.awesomium.com/)) to build "my own" chrome browser in c++ :)